# BOM variations of parts

Tags: database-design

I am designing a database for a manufacturing process. One of the tasks is to be able to generate a Bill Of Materials (BOM). The basic design like the one at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx is sufficient.

However, there is one big issue I need in addition. I need to be able to select an assembly based on some calculation. The data come from a product configurator. And e.g. based on the size of the product I need to use different assemblies or parts.

To illustrate: the root of the tree is a BOM1 that comprises of BOM21 and BOM22. BOM21 comprises of BOM31 and BOM32 and another BOM which can either be BOM33 or BOM34. The decision of BOM33 or BOM34 depends on the input data. How do I approach this issue in database design?

My first idea was to create a BOM35. This BOM35 would be assigned a stored procedure which would select the proper BOM instead. But it is quite clumsy. What is the standard way or ways of approaching this issue?

To illustrate the problem I made two sketches (diamonds show where it is necessary to decide, depending on the parameters from the configurator):

**1. The decision takes place at the Parts list level:**

[image: Decision at the part list level]

**2. The decision takes place at the BOM level:**

[image: Decision at the BOM level]

Thank you.

Comment: I think your definition of `BOM1` is not complete, and will make your life harder than it should be. *"[there is] is a BOM1 that comprises of [...], [as well as] another BOM which can either be [...]"*. I'm pretty sure that if it "can either be" something else depending on the input, it isn't truly a `BOM1`. Can you redefine how you compose these BOMs? I would think that `BOM1` is always the same, and a new BOM is needed to account for the varied input for (in this case) `BOM33` vs. `BOM34`.

Comment: I was not sure how to respond to your comment, so I decided to draw the  BOMs to make it more clear. The illustrations are in the text of the original question.Whether the BOM1 depends on the input data depends at which level I do the decision making. To illustrate more, BOM1 can comprise of a finished product and packaging but depending on the size of the product (which is selected in the configurator), the packaging can either be carton board or plastic.